# Launch default browser from Android's captive portal browser (CaptivePortalLogin)

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, captivenetwork

On Android devices, our captive portal launches in Android's Captive Portal Browser. After authentication, we redirect the user to a status page, where they can see their session information, remaining time and data, etc. Most users choose to keep this page open.

The problem is that the status page redirect happens within the Captive Portal browser, which will eventually close. Is there any way that we can open the status page, in a 'full' browser, form within the Captive Portal browser?

Most of the relevant Android code seems to be in CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java. The mBrowserBailOutToken variable looks interesting but I don't see how we can get the token.

Any other ideas on how to handle a situation like this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hi J. Johnson i'm looking for the same thing, did you find a solution ? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you find something that might achieve that?

Comment: I also want to know how to redirect to the external browser from within android webview. @j-johnson did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible.

The mBrowserBailOut variable is [set to a random number](https://github.com/nikitagaba/Android/blob/master/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java#L316) so you have no change to know that one from within the captive portal page.

Only if the redirect [URL contains this variable](https://github.com/nikitagaba/Android/blob/master/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java#L332) it bails out.

The variable is used in cases there is an [SSL error](https://github.com/nikitagaba/Android/blob/master/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java#L394), so in case you have such, it would prompt the user to use the default browser.

EDIT: I mean what is funny, is that the URL only [has to contain the token somewhere](https://github.com/nikitagaba/Android/blob/master/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java#L332). So in theory you could make up an URL that contains all the possible tokens.

```
Long.MAX_VALUE is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.
```

So that are far too much possibilities that fit into an URL, despite that fact that smaller numbers are already contained in larger ones.